# How to fetch Outlook mail body in Html format?

Tags: vb.net, email, c#-4.0, outlook

I developed one vb.net form that have all mail of my Outlook inbox with "Next" and "Prev" button.I am able to fetch all details like "SenderName","SenderEmail","Body" etc.Now problem i am facing is that the body of mail not coming in HTML format.I need body in HTML format to show on vb.net form.

here is my current code.

```
 myItems.Item(currentindexparam).BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML

    lblsub.Text = myItems.Item(currentindexparam).Subject
    lblform.Text = myItems.Item(currentindexparam).SenderEmailAddress
    txt_body.Text = myItems.Item(currentindexparam).Body
    lbldate.Text = myItems.Item(currentindexparam).ReceivedTime

    _currentindex = currentindexparam


    Dim Atmt As Outlook.Attachment

    For Each Atmt In myItems.Item(currentindexparam).Attachments
        Dim filename As String = "C:\Email Attachments\" + Atmt.FileName
        Atmt.SaveAsFile(filename)
    Next Atmt
```

let me know if you have any idea about it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [MailItem.HTMLBody Property (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941.aspx).